# Bin numbers in line of file to group elegantly

Tags: java, arrays, string, scala, binning

I have a text-file which looks like outlined below. It contains a header of 6 lines and then only numeric values (integers). I would like to bin these integers to a range lets assume values are in range from 0 ... 50 I would like to bin them to 5 *groups* i.e. bin to `0...10...20...30...40...50`

Is there some elegant way to bin them?

```
ncols 4
nrows 3
xllcorner 0
yllcorner 0
cellsize 1
nodata_value -999
1 2 3 4
4 21 3 3
3 2 31 1
```

Currently I use an iterator for the lines of the file and tokenize the values within a line using a scanner - this seems rather clumsy. Looking forward for some elegant ideas.

Expected output would be

```
ncols 4
nrows 3
xllcorner 0
yllcorner 0
cellsize 1
nodata_value -999
1 1 1 1
1 2 1 1
1 1 3 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
object Test {

  def main(args:Array[String]):Unit={
    val source = scala.io.Source.fromFile("/ssd2/test.txt")
    val lines = source.getLines().toList
    val (header, payload) = (lines.take(6), lines.drop(6))

    def classify(i:Int):Int = (i / 10) + 1

    val binned = payload.map{line =>
      line.split(" ").map(n => classify(n.toInt)).mkString(" ")
    }

    val result = header ++ binned
    result.foreach(println(_))
  }

}
```

Although the output is

```
ncols 4
nrows 3
xllcorner 0
yllcorner 0
cellsize 1
nodata_value -999
1 1 1 1
1 3 1 1
1 1 4 1
```

I think you have a small bug in your expected output sample.